# Как переписать Shell код на GNU parallell код?

Tags: bash, shell, gnu

```
list=`cat SRAIdFromPythonInput.txt` # list of the SRA record file 
  IDs.
    for i in $list
    do  echo $i
   ./fastq-dump --split-files $i -v
    done
```

как переписать это на GNU paralell "`cat list | parallel "do-something1 {} config-{} ; do-something2 < {}" | process-output`"?

Answer (score 0):

> как переписать это на GNU paralell

честно говоря, не имею ни малейшего представления, как это «переписать» и зачем вообще нужно «переписывать».

если вам всего лишь нужно использовать программу *parallel*, так используйте её прямо так, как у вас и написано:

```
$ cat SRAIdFromPythonInput.txt | parallel ./fastq-dump --split-files -v
```

Comment: вроде можно еще `parallel -j COUNT_NUMBER ./fastq-dump --split-files {} -v < SRAIdFromPythonInput.txt` указывая количество джобов

Comment: *указывая количество джобов* — у программы *gnu/parallel* огромный список всяческих опций. перечислять их все в ответе вряд ли имеет смысл.